# How to divide IloNumExpr from Cplex?

Tags: java, cplex

I'm using Java to solve a maximization problem in Cplex.
My objective function is quite complex. In a nutshell, there are two parts, A and B. Both of them contain variables.

My goal is to maximize A/B, but the problem is that, the Cplex only allows me to do the **production operation**. I try to use the **reciprocal of B** to solve this problem, but the reciprocal of an expression is **also not allowed**.

[image]

In the attached figure, "objective" is part A, and "cost" is the B. Both of them are IloNumExpr.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: `cost` is not a number. it is an object. java has no operator overloading. you need to create an instance of that class that represents the number `1` and then check if there is some sort of `divide` in that class. so something along the lines of `new Foo(1).divide(bar)`. Unless you actually wanted to get `int`, then u have to unwrap the `cost` to the `int` it contains. so something like `1 / cost.getInt()` (I am just guessing the method names since I dont know this class and library).

Comment: I know COST is an object. My question is how to do the divide operation in Cplex. Cplex only provides two operations between NumExprs (or you can say they are objects), which are Cplex.prod and Cplex.sum. I wonder if there is any way that I can do the divide operation, as there is no Cplex.divide.

Comment: is it possible to find an object C, which, when multiplied with B, produce a plain number? if so, you can just multiply both A and B with C, and scale the product of A and C with the reciprocal of the product of B and C.

Comment: Both B and A contain variables, I'm not sure if it is possible to find such object C.
I have tried a similar way. I define a C and make a constraint to force C*B=1 so that I can use A*C instead of A/B. But it seems like CPLEX does not allow me to make this constraint.